# NHibernate InvalidProxyTypeException

Tags: nhibernate

I get this NHhiberante when verifying my Fluent Mappings

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
>   : An invalid or incomplete
>   configuration was used while creating
>   a SessionFactory. Check
>   PotentialReasons collection, and
>   InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---->
>   NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException :
>   The following types may not be used as
>   proxies: Domain.Address: method
>   Equals should be 'public/protected
>   virtual' or 'protected internal
>   virtual' Domain.Person: method
>   Equals should be 'public/protected
>   virtual' or 'protected internal
>   virtual' TearDown :
>   System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

I Tried making my Equals method virtual however I just end up getting this error

> System.ApplicationException : For
>   property 'AddressPerson' expected
>   'Domain.Person' of type
>   'Domain.Person' but got
>   'PersonProxy5ce0cdda11ac4829a4f038c9f7944213'
>   of type 'Domain.Person'

I am confused does anyone know what exactly is going on here?

Edit: It looks like you cant override : Equals(Person person) for IEquatable Not sure why this confuses NHibernate however?

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned in your edit, yes you can't implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for an NHibernate entity class. Just override the simple public override `bool Equals(object obj)` and `public override int GetHashCode()`.